# AWS SAM golang lambda localhost connection refused to postgres

Tags: postgresql, go, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli, sam

I'm unable to connect an AWS SAM lambda function to a local postgres instance.  I'll be specific in a moment, but first let me say that the same code works for my coworker and that I've tried using Postgres within a docker container as well as installed manually.  To simplify the problem I started over with the SAM helloworld golang example and added the following:

```
import (
  _ "github.com/lib/pq"
  "database/sql"
)
.
.
.
const (
    host     = "localhost"
    port     = 5432
    user     = "postgres"
    password = "postgres"
    dbname   = "postgres"
)
.
.
.
.
psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+
    "password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
    host, port, user, password, dbname)

db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer db.Close()

err = db.Ping()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println("Successfully connected!")
```

And I get the following error:

```
dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused: OpError
[{"path":"github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go@v1.13.3/lambda/function.go","line":35,"label":"(*Function).Invoke.func1"},{"path":"runtime/panic.go","line":969,"label":"gopanic"},{"path":"hello-world/main.go","line":67,"label":"handler"},{"path":"reflect/value.go","line":475,"label":"Value.call"},{"path":"reflect/value.go","line":336,"label":"Value.Call"},{"path":"github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go@v1.13.3/lambda/handler.go","line":124,"label":"NewHandler.func1"},{"path":"github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go@v1.13.3/lambda/handler.go","line":24,"label":"lambdaHandler.Invoke"},{"path":"github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go@v1.13.3/lambda/function.go","line":67,"label":"(*Function).Invoke"},{"path":"reflect/value.go","line":475,"label":"V
alue.call"},{"path":"reflect/value.go","line":336,"label":"Value.Call"},{"path":"net/rpc/server.go","line":377,"label":"(*service).call"},{"path":"runtime/asm_amd64.s","line":1374,"label":"goexit"}]
```

SAM CLI, version 1.21.1

I've now tried this on two machines and get the same error.  Is there there something that I'm just missing there? I can confirm that the the database is receiving connections fine. I hit it every day from a node app.  Also, I can build the golang code outside of SAM and it will work fine.  So there's something with my SAM setup that's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I spend a lot of time figuring out how to connect using AWS SAM to a local Postgres and finally found that changing the dbhostname from `localhost` to `host.docker.internal` works.

```
connectionString = 'postgresql://dbuser:dbpassword@host.docker.internal:5432/dbname';
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  Within the lambda I needed to set the postgres connection string to hit `host.docker.internal`